# Eclipse generate WSDL use Java Class minOccus=0 setting

Tags: java, web-services

I had defined a java class for web service data input

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MaterialDoc {
    public String workid;
    public String mblnr;
    public double mblpo;
}
```

And define a web service

```
public class MaterialInterface {

    public void generateProcess(Material[] inboundDocs) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

use Eclipse generate web service the generated WSDL like below

```
<complexType name="Material">
    <sequence>
      <element name="workid" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="mblnr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="mblpo" type="xsd:double"/>
```

But, I want allow some tags are optional, the WSDL like

```
<element name="workid" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

How to adjust my Java class? Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

change `mblpo` from the basic type `double` to the Object `Double`.

Comment: change data type double to Double still not display minOccurs="0"